# IS this causing Abandoned memory?

Tags: ios, ios5, memory-management, abandoned-memory

I'm looking at heap shots in memory. This function seems to be a culprit for abandoned memory.

It'S part of view building code for one of my view , 'MyView'.

If I create and destroy 'MyView' 100 times with this function commented memory size always returns to it base line. However if I leave this function in my memory continually increases.

As far as I can see I dont take ownership of anything in the function.
What am I doing wrong?

```
-(void)drawPointAroundCircle:(CGPoint)centerpoint radius:(int)radius amount:(int)amount
{


    CGPoint pointarray[amount];
    float thetaarray[7]={270.0,315.0,0.0,45.0,135,180.0,225.0};
    int i=-1;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height));

    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    for (i=0; i<7; i++) {




        float x=cosf(D2R( thetaarray[i]))*radius;
        float y =sinf( D2R(thetaarray[i]))*radius;
        x=x+centerpoint.x;
        y=y+centerpoint.y;

        pointarray[i].x=x;
        pointarray[i].y=y;

        UIBezierPath *path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(x, y) radius:2 startAngle:D2R(0) endAngle:D2R(360) clockwise:YES];

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);      


        [path fill];
        [path closePath];
        }



    UIImage *bezierimage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView *bezierImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:bezierimage];

    [self addSubview:bezierImageView];

}
```

Comment: Do you ever remove the subviews again or do you keep going adding one subview after each other? Within that method you create bezierviewImage and addSubView will retain it. ReleaseFromSuperview would release it in terms of memory allocation too (meaning reduce the retain count by 1).

Comment: Bah!!! 99% of my project uses arc. 'MyView' is the 1% that does not. I never called release. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bezierImageview should be autoreleased before adding it to the subview or released after adding it to the subview. The retain count for that object can never fall below 1 with your current code.

This is assuming non-ARC, but if you were using ARC it wouldn't be leaking.

Comment: see my embarrassing comment below my question. Thanks

Comment: 1% of my projects use ARC, so I assume it's not on, which can also be embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

You are, in fact, "taking ownership" of something with this line:

```
UIImageView *bezierImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:bezierimage];
```

If you're not using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), you should autorelease bezierImageView before the end of the method.